# I've installed pyglet and I still can't get it working?

Tags: python, pyglet

I have pip, and I went into Terminal and typed `pip install pyglet`.  Everything worked fine, and it told me that pyglet was successfully installed.  However, once I opened a test .py file with `import pyglet` and ran it, it told me there was "no such moduled 'pyglet'". How do I get it working?  I'm running OSX 10.10.2.

Comment: What are the results of running `python -V` and `pip --version` in Terminal? Most likely `pip` is associated with a different version of Python than the one you used to run your test program.

Comment: Ah, that's the issue.  They're both associated with Python 2.7, but I run Python 3.4.  Any idea how I should fix that?

Comment: Pyglet 1.2 works with Python 3. If you want to install it, you can use `pip3 install pyglet` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have python 3.5.1 and pip is associated with python35-32. I have ran PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:/python/pyglet which is where I extracted pyglet to. I still get "no module pyglet" when running pyglet's test.py. Pip gives me requirement satisfied and requirement up to date when I try to install and upgrade pyglet. Any ideas?